# How to remove an environment from the project?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Is it possible to remove a mobile environment from the project like say Blackberry and Adobe Air environments. For instance

```
mobilefirst add environment
```

helps to add environment, but is there a command to remove an environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CLI does not have a command to "remove an environment".
You can submit feature requests, here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/

Your only alternative is:

1. Navigate to the application folder and delete the environment directory as you would remove any other directory/folder in a filesystem from command line.

   - Windows: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55721-folder-delete-command-prompt.html
   - Linux/Mac: http://www.macworld.com/article/2082021/master-the-command-line-deleting-files-and-folders.html
2. You can then optionally also edit application-descriptor.xml to remove it from there as well (not removing it will trigger a warning).